# Why does this `aureport` show a question mark in the 'exe' field?

Tags: security, audit, linux-audit

I'm trying to debug why my docker socket changes ownership on a weekly basis.
I created an audit log rule on /var/run/docker.sock.

The audit report shows me many events happening to that socket, but it is not
showing me which process triggered each event. Instead it prints a '?' in the 'exe' field. Why would this be?

Here's some truncated output:

```
    Key Report
===============================================
# date time key success exe auid event
===============================================
1. 03/04/17 06:54:09 docker-sock-attributes yes ? -1 108449
2. 03/04/17 06:54:09 docker-sock-attributes yes ? -1 108450
3. 03/04/17 06:54:10 docker-sock-attributes yes ? -1 108453
```

Comment: Are you manually changing the permissions? The permissions of the socket are probably on service start. Does restarting docker reproduce the issue?